# Accessing php $_SESSION from python (wsgi) - is it possible?

Tags: php, python, session, wsgi

I've got a python/WSGI app which needs to check to see if a user has logged on to a PHP web app. The problem is that the PHP app checks if a user has logged on by comparing a value in the $_SESSION variable to a value in the cookie from the user's browser. I would prefer to avoid changing the behavior of the php app if at all possible.

My questions:

1. Is there anyway I can access the session variables from within python? Where should I start to look?
2. Are there any obvious security/performance issues I should be aware of when taking this approach?

Answer (score 4):

1. yep. session (in default) is a regular file. so all what you need is look over session directory and find file with name of session cookie value. then - you have to implement php-like serialize/unserialize and do whatever you want.
2. nope

Comment: The link in David's comment is broken. Instead I've found this gist: https://gist.github.com/scragg0x/3894835

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the PHP app, if it's keeping session data in a database (MySQL maybe) you can just connect to the database and get the data, if it's using native PHP sessions you should look to the `session.save_path` config setting in php.ini, that's the place where the runtime saves files with the session data.

Once you have the data you can parse it to get it unserialized, take a look at how `serialize()` and `unserialize()` work in PHP.

Comment: I recommend and use this solution. It's actually very simple to write a mysql-based session manager - and using the custom session methods you can also store the session data as JSON, which makes it universally accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in the process of trying to run a python server side by side with an existing Apache/php one. A custom solution I arrived at was to save the $_SESSION as an encrypted cookie, letting the php authentication operate as before, then share a private key between the two servers.

Two issues:

- Up to you how to handle session expiry stuff.
- I haven't bothered with an Initialization Vector, assuming the time stamp from my expiry stuff is enough. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486940/4495503 for why I might be being too security lax...

Anyway, my php encrypted cookie function:

```
session_start();
    $encryptToCookie = function($varToEncode,$cookieName,$privateKey){
        $iv = $privateKey;
        $pass = $privateKey;
        $method = 'aes-128-cbc';
        $encryptedString = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($varToEncode), $method, $pass, true, $iv);
        setcookie($cookieName,bin2hex($encryptedString));
    };

$encryptToCookie($_SESSION,"sessionEncrypted","yohoyohoyohoyoho"); // private key must be 16bit
```

And my python side decryption:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import binascii

def decrypt(encryptedString,privateKey):
    encryptedString = binascii.unhexlify(encryptedString)  
    pathToOpenSSL = 'C:\pysrc\openssl\openssl.exe' # MODIFY THIS!! 

    openssl = Popen([pathToOpenSSL,
                     'enc','-aes-128-cbc','-d',
                     '-nosalt','-nopad','-K',
                     privateKey.encode('hex'),
                     '-iv',
                     privateKey.encode('hex')],
                     stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
    decryptedString = openssl.communicate(encryptedString)[0].replace('\x04','')
    return decryptedString

decrypt(encryptedString,'yohoyohoyohoyoho')
```

Hope this is of help to someone, remember all the usual stuff about generating private keys and then being careful with them!