# User authentication in tornado based on other php site

Tags: php, session, authentication, tornado

I wrote my own **long-pollig Tornado/AJAX chat** with rooms , whisper messages and other cool stuff . Till now as user authentication for just test purposes i've been using cookies . So u had to just enter your name ,after what cokie 'user' was created and chat would react accordingly to that cookie . But the problem is that i wrote this chat for a friend which has a php site. So basically i **need to authenticate users based on his sessions.** Thats where i got confused. *And i am very ashamed* , because i caught myself on a thought that i don't know how exactly session work , which is kind of absurd, because i don't consider myself such a bad programmer ^^ Well shit happens. Well ofcourse i know that sessions only store id on the client and other information is stored on the server , but that doesn't really help because i need know excatly what happens in details .  Sure i googled a bit , but still am confused how to solve this problem. So the basic questions are :

**1)** Would appreciate if someone could in details explain one more time exactly how sessions work , and what i need know or have access to on php site ,  to use sessions in another application ...

**2)**So for example when i authenticate on my django site ,session is created with some value like 's5ds6dssd6' , and to tell the truth i don't know what to further do with it.Ashamed again. For example in PHP to extract  username (if it was set) and check/do something i would do something like  PHP_SESSION['username'] === ... .In django even less work just to use decorator or user.is_authenticated method. Yet how works inside and what i need i don't know.

---

There is a big chance what i wrote is stupid , and it's very easy , and i am a moron , which wrote before trying ...Yet even if i somehow would be able to get data from sessions/php site  how could i be sure that some guy didn't create session with random id by himself , without authencating on php site ....

Well hope someone could point me in right direction . It felt necessary to write so much so you could udnerstand =) what bothers me and respond accordingly....  Sorry if i wrote something stupid.

Comment: I guess i found what i was looking for and the only way to do this is to find session file in php directory and serialize it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534525/accessing-php-session-from-python-wsgi-is-it-possible

Comment: Another one... http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=10855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Would appreciate if someone could
>   in details explain one more time
>   exactly how sessions work , and what i
>   need know or have access to on php
>   site , to use sessions in another
>   application ...

**P.S: I am using [Linux](http://www.google.nl/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=linux)(I use the freely available [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) which is the most popular/user-friendly Linux [distro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)) as [OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) below and I would advice you to use a *nx distro(MacOSX is also pretty good but expensive in my opinion) as well with all your webdevelopment although all these commands are also available in [Cygwin(windows)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).**

[Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) are:

> Session support in PHP consists of a
>   way to preserve certain data across
>   subsequent accesses. This enables you
>   to build more customized applications
>   and increase the appeal of your web
>   site.

Below I try to explain what sessions are and how they are using cookies

---

I created a simple `no.php` which does not use sessions and simply outputs `Hello World`:

```
Hello World
```

When we [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) this script **with the [headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) using -v** we get the following output:

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/www/6500588$ curl http://localhost/6500588/no.php -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /6500588/no.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2011 02:10:53 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 12
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
Hello World
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

As you can see from the output no [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) has been set. If you do this repeatedly you will get the same output.

---

Next I create a simple `yes.php` file which does make use of sessions.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}

echo $_SESSION['count']++;
```

Let's show the output from curl without storing the cookie:

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/www/6500588$ curl http://localhost/6500588/yes.php -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /6500588/yes.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2011 02:12:47 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=hrduhht116e9mikhkkj0gu7126; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 1
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
0
```

As you can see the count is `0`, but also a cookie has been set: `Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=hrduhht116e9mikhkkj0gu7126; path=/`. with [session_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) `hrduhht116e9mikhkkj0gu7126`

---

If we do not store this cookie when we issue the same curl command again we wil still receive `0` as answer(forget to count) and also receive another cookie.

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/www/6500588$ curl http://localhost/6500588/yes.php -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /6500588/yes.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2011 02:16:42 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ihlj9c9fifl8f0lklu0umesas2; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 1
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
0
```

As you can see `hrduhht116e9mikhkkj0gu7126` is not equal to `ihlj9c9fifl8f0lklu0umesas2` which means a new cookie has been set and the information in that session is lost.

---

Next we store the cookie to `cookie` file issuing `-c` flag

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/www/6500588$ curl http://localhost/6500588/yes.php -v -c cookie
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /6500588/yes.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2011 02:27:11 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
* Added cookie PHPSESSID="1h6710hhk84e0k9bj2kg7p03u5" for domain localhost, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1h6710hhk84e0k9bj2kg7p03u5; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 1
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
0
```

As you can see from `ls`(directory listing) we stored cookie to file named `cookie`.

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/www/6500588$ ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 alfred alfred 4096 2011-06-28 04:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 alfred alfred 4096 2011-06-28 03:59 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 alfred alfred  196 2011-06-28 04:27 cookie
-rw-r--r--  1 alfred alfred   12 2011-06-28 04:00 no.php
-rw-r--r--  1 alfred alfred  114 2011-06-28 04:12 yes.php
```

---

That cookie to keep track of the count contains the following information according to `cat`(shows output of file)

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/www/6500588$ cat cookie 
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

localhost   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   1h6710hhk84e0k9bj2kg7p03u5
```

---

We next use that cookie to keep track of the count.

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/www/6500588$ curl http://localhost/6500588/yes.php -v -b cookie
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /6500588/yes.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: PHPSESSID=1h6710hhk84e0k9bj2kg7p03u5
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2011 02:40:18 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 1
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
1
```

As you can see we used that cookie with the same ID `1h6710hhk84e0k9bj2kg7p03u5` and the count is `1` instead of `0` when we don't use any cookie(or not store cookie and get new cookie).

---

> So basically i need to authenticate
>   users based on his sessions.

sessions are just simple using cookies([sessionid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)) under the cover. You could for example override the standard implementation for [sessions to use the database](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database) instead of the filesystem(interesting read!). But I would just use the [session_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) you receive from PHP(`session_id`) within your tornado application to authenticate your session because that should be unique(hard to guess).

> session_id() returns the session id
>   for the current session or the empty
>   string ("") if there is no current
>   session (no current session id
>   exists).

---

**P.S: I hope this answers your question a little bit. If not you could ask in the comments for a little bit more information?**

Comment: I am debian user myself =). Thx for the answer .Pretty much you answered everything i needed. I was jsut unsure would i be able to fetch id , and if i would ,then i should have access to php site database in order to pull user data . True i could use id's :D.But i guess they'd appreciate nicks more.   Thx for your time , wasted on my stupid question =)

Comment: You could just serialize your $_SESSION data and send it over the wire when both server's(PHP server with node server) communicate. It would be as simple as echo `json_encode($_SESSION);` to save the session information?